# What is wrong with PrintWindow?

Tags: winapi, screenshot

What is wrong with the following code? Why does `PrintWindow` return 0?

```
HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
CHK(hwnd);

HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
CHK(hdc);

if (hdc)
{
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    CHK(hdcMem);

    if (hdcMem)
    {
        RECT rc;
        CHK(GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc));

        HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right-rc.left, rc.bottom-rc.top);
        CHK(hbitmap);   

        if (hbitmap)
        {
            SelectObject(hdcMem, hbitmap);

            CHK(PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcMem, 0)); //HERE return 0

            DeleteObject(hbitmap);
        }

        DeleteObject(hdcMem);
    }

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060746/general-capturing-with-wm-print-and-wm-printclient-supported-on-at-least-window.

Answer (score 2):

`PrintWindow` is a fairly thin operation. What it really does is post a `WM_PRINT`message to the queue for the window in question, in this case the desktop, and hopes that that window will respond to `WM_PRINT` correctly if at all (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Win32-GDI/29825132/problems-with-printwindow-api-function.aspx)).

I repro'd your behavior but I'm not 100% sure why it's failing either. Perhaps you cannot call `PrintWindow` on an `HWND` that your process does not own, or perhaps the desktop does not respond to `WM_PRINT` messages.

The second link above includes a comment about using [`BitBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead:

> Try getting a handle (HWND) to the
>   desktop window - and use `BitBlt` to
>   capture all the contents.  Mind you -
>   you'll only capture what is visible on
>   the screen.

Maybe this helps.

Comment: Your second link is broken. Since it reads "here", it's not recoverable by others.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `GetDesktopWindow()` returns a *virtual* HWND whose value is universally 0x0010010 on all Windows machines. This virtual HWND does not conform to usual PrintWindow behavior so the PrintWindow() returns FALSE, and GetLastError() reports no error code on this PrintWindow call.

To make PrintWindow() work, you can instead use the HWND from `GetShellWindow()`, which has the title "Program Manager" from the WinSpy++ figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
```

With:

```
HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
hwnd = FindWindowEx( hwnd, 0, _T("Progman"), _T("Program Manager") );
```

I'm not sure whether this gets what you want though. If you want to take a screenshot of the entire current desktop (including whatever top level windows are visible) then BitBlt is the route you want to take.

If you want to get the taskbar as well, you can still use this method but you'll have to take 2 screenshots and stitch the results together.