# General capturing with WM_PRINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT, supported on at least Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, gdi, capture

So far I got this partially working capturing function in C#:

```
/// <summary>
/// Captures a HWND, using a WM_PRINT windows message to draw into a memory DC.
/// Pro: Does also work if  the HWND is not positioned inside the visible screen.
/// Con: Does only work if the target handle supports WM_PRINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT.
/// TODO: Subclass the target handle and hack the WM_PRINT support for various systems, including Windows 7.
///       Example for Windows 2000 see http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWnd">The HWND.</param>
/// <returns>Bitmap of the captured visual window, if the operation succeeds. Null, if the operation fails.</returns>
public static Bitmap CaptureHWnd_WM_PRINT(UIntPtr hWnd)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    UIntPtr hDC = User32.GetWindowDC(hWnd); //Get the device context of hWnd
    if (hDC != UIntPtr.Zero)
    {
        UIntPtr hMemDC = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC); //Create a memory device context, compatible with hDC
        if (hMemDC != UIntPtr.Zero)
        {
            RECT rc; MyGetWindowRect(hWnd, out rc); //Get bounds of hWnd
            UIntPtr hbitmap = Gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, rc.Width, rc.Height); //Create a bitmap handle, compatible with hDC
            if (hbitmap != UIntPtr.Zero)
            {
                UIntPtr hOld = Gdi32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hbitmap); //Select hbitmap into hMemDC
                //#also tried: User32.SendMessage(hWnd, WM.PRINT, hMemDC, (UIntPtr)(DrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT | DrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN | DrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT | DrawingOptions.PRF_OWNED));
                User32.DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM.PRINT, hMemDC, (UIntPtr)(DrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT | DrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN | DrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT | DrawingOptions.PRF_OWNED));
                bitmap = Image.FromHbitmap(hbitmap.ToIntPtr()); //Create a managed Bitmap out of hbitmap
                Gdi32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld); //Select hOld into hMemDC (the previously replaced object), to leave hMemDC as found
                Gdi32.DeleteObject(hbitmap); //Free hbitmap
            }
            Gdi32.DeleteDC(hMemDC); //Free hdcMem
        }
        User32.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC); //Free hDC
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

The problem is, that it can only work if *hWnd* handles the WM_PRINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT messages correctly.
For example, one can test it sucessfully using

```
UIntPtr hWndMyButton = User32.CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX.NONE, "Button", " HELLO WORLD! :) ", WS.CHILD,
    5000, 5000,
    200, 30, User32.GetDesktopWindow(), (UIntPtr)0x8807, UIntPtr.Zero, UIntPtr.Zero);
Bitmap capture = CaptureHWnd_WM_PRINT(hWndMyButton);
```

, but for the most cases it only results in a black image of the size of *hWnd*. Note that *hWndMyButton* is far outside the screen bounds (at position {X=5000,Y=5000}), but can still get captured. That is the reason I need WM_PRINT.

The questions is now, **how can I force hWnd to handle the print messages correctly on at least Windows 7?**

So far, I found [this](http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html) solution for Windows 2000 and would like to get a similar solution for Windows 7, or preferred a generic solution for all Windows systems that support WM_PRINT.
Unfortunately I could not find anything for other systems than Windows 2000.

Comment: There's no need to use `WM_PRINT` or `WM_PRINTCLIENT` at all. Use `BitBlt` to transfer from the source DC (your `hDC`) into your `hMemDC` directly, using the width and height you retrieved with `GetWindowRect` (`width = rc.Right - rc.Left; height = rc.Bottom - rc.Top`;`).

Comment: That's wrong. When I come from the window DC, everything that is outside the screenbounds is black, since Windows would not update anything that is outside the screen bounds. I'll edit my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: No, it's not wrong. I have working (WinAPI, not .NET) code that does screen captures of windows without once asking for anything using `WM_PRINT` or `WM_PRINTCLIENT`; it's translated into Delphi code, and I use it on multiple Windows versions (it started out in Win95 days, worked through XP, Win2K, Win2003, Win7, and Win2008 - I haven't tested it yet on Win8, because I don't have a Win8 machine available currently).

Comment: So can you provide an example that is able to capture a window that is larger than the screen but still get captured correctly? That would be an answer to my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001654/how-to-force-a-foreign-window-to-redraw-its-client-area-somewhere-outside-the-vi).

Comment: Actually, you're correct. I missed the part of your requirement that it is capturing "off-screen windows", which isn't going to work properly for you for windows that don't implement WM_PRINT, because Windows doesn't draw windows that can't be seen (for performance and resource reasons); that may be the reason you're having difficulty with WM_PRINT as well, because Windows doesn't want to draw them at all.

Comment: It simply isn't supported by every window.  A browser is the most notorious example.  Or the programmer just forgot to implement it.  Nothing you can do about it but fall back to a plain screen-shot.

Comment: As shown by [example](http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html) there is something one can do about it.

Comment: If you have that example that shows "there is something one can do about it", what exactly do you need us for?

Comment: Maybe I'm lucky and somebody dealt with this before. I read some parts of the authors book (e.g. 'Chapter 4. Spying in the Windows Graphics System' seems to be very interesting for this topic) and came to the conclusion that such a solution is a huge (maybe unnecessary) workload for someone who is rather unexperienced with this, like me.

Comment: On recent Windows 10, there's a problem with security of DC handles which cannot be used on the other side of the messaging channel. So the example linked by @xamid probably must be extended.